# an identity between two elliptic integrals

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I would like a direct change of variable proof of the identity

$$\int_0^{\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^2\phi }}d\phi=\int_0^{\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^22\phi }}d\phi\,.$$ 
I need it as part of a paper on Legendre's proof of the "third singular modulus."

Comment: your $d\phi$ are not where they should be.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik thank you, now corrected.

Comment: Instead of writing $\sqrt{\sqrt3}$, you might use either $3^{1/4}$ or $\sqrt[4]{3}$, LaTeX for the latter is \sqrt[4]{3}.

Comment: Isn't math.se a right forum for such questions?

Comment: Mathematica reduces it to $$F\left(2 \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{3}\right)|\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)=2 F\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)|\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)\right)$$ with http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html

Comment: @user64494 Once again, not everything for which a CAS provides an answer (but no explanation!) deserves your "isn't MSE a right forum for such questions". Note that the OP desires a proof, presumably seeking understanding

Comment: @user64494 I agree with Yemon's response. Even worse, such comments serve to "shame" the OP for even asking here, when in fact the question is perfectly on-topic, for the reasons Yemon gave. Please reflect carefully on this.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I don't know either the motivation or intention of the person who commented above, but it's pretty clear that there is a lot of expertise on MSE for computing every definite integral under the sun, certainly a lot more than has ever been demonstrated on MO. There's actually a case to be made for some definite integral questions that MSE is a better place because there are more experts there. I would ask you to reflect on whether any suggestion that MSE might be better is automatically "shaming" rather than actually directing the OP to a more useful site.

Comment: @ElectricPenguin Thanks. Interesting point. I do question your assertion that there is more skill at Mathematics for solving such problems, but next time I see a case where this community finds a definite integral question on-topic and is defeated by it, I'll think about it. But based on a long history, it seems user64494 says the same thing just about every time he sees a definite integral problem for which Mathematica gives an answer (and, tbh, user's formulation sounds a bit rhetorical to me, as if asking "shouldn't you know better?", thus prompting my comment).

Comment: @ToddTrimble, no problem! I agree with you that the way it was phrased in this particular example was non-optimal and I certainly don't know about past histories.

Comment: Two edits in the bounty offer:  $theta$ should be replaced by $\theta$ and $\arctan(1/\sqrt(3)$ should be replaced by $\arctan(1/\sqrt(\sqrt(3))$

Comment: I think $\theta$ should be equated to $2\arctan 3^{-1/4}$, see the answer box where I have tried to work this out in some detail.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker  Yes, you are right.  I miscopied the identity...$\theta$ should be equated to $2\arctan 3^{-\frac{1}{4}}$.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since the bountied question has changed substantially, now asking for the application of an identity in Legendre's [Traite des fonctions elliptiques](https://archive.org/details/traitedesfonctio01amle/page/n33), I am starting a new answer. Legendre defines
\begin{align}
&F(\phi,k)=\int_0^{\phi}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi'}},\\
&\sin\phi=\frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta(\theta)}},\;\;\Delta(\theta)=\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta},
\end{align}
and then derives the identity
$$F(\phi,k)=\tfrac{1}{2}F(\theta,k).$$
Now we apply this to $k^2=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}$, $\theta=2 \arctan 3^{-1/4}$ and find 
$$\sin\phi=\frac{2 \sin (\theta/2)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{4-\left(\sqrt{3}+2\right) \sin ^2\theta}+2}}=\sqrt{3}-1,$$
and thus $\phi=\arcsin(\sqrt{3}-1)=\arctan\left(3^{-1/4}\sqrt{2}\right)$. Hence, Legendre's identity gives
$$F\left(\arctan\left(3^{-1/4}\sqrt{2}\right),\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}F\left(2 \arctan 3^{-1/4},\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$$
or equivalently
$$\int_0^{\arctan\left(3^{-1/4}\sqrt{2}\right)}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^2 \phi'}}=\int_0^{\arctan 3^{-1/4}}\frac{d\phi'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^2 2\phi'}},$$
which is the identity in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet an answer, but a bit too long for a comment. The [Legendre normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) of these elliptic integrals might be a first step, at least by introducing simpler integration limits:
\begin{align}
&I_1=\int_0^{\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}}} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^2\phi }}=\int_0^{\sqrt{3}-1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}t^2)}}, \\
&I_2=\int_0^{\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}}}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin^22\phi }}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{3^{1/4}(\sqrt{3}-1)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}t^2)}}.
\end{align}